# Create events in Exchange Server 2003 from a website

Tags: events, calendar, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2003

I researched and found there is no EWS for Exchange Server 2003.
I need to create events in Exchange Server Calendar through my website.
So how can I create an event through my website?

Comment: and what is your Question ?????

Comment: How can I create an event through my website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Exchange 2003 you have 3 client API options for creating appointments you can use either MAPI via the Outlook OOM or a third party library like Redemption http://www.dimastr.com/redemption , you could use CDOEX or exOledb but this only would work directly on the Exchange Server or WebDAV https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms877306%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Thank You. The client is upgrading his server from Exchange 2003 to the latest version. So, hopefully I could use EWS itself.